# Windows 10 Upgrade closes after "What do you want to do?" screen

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I'm trying to upgrade a Win 7 SP1 Home Premium 64-bit laptop of mine to Windows 10 so that I can play around with it before installing it on my primary desktop. The laptop exceeds all of the Windows 10 minimum specifications (latest OS, > 1 GHz processor, > 2 GB of RAM, > 20 GB of HDD space, > DirectX 9, and > 800x600 display) listed on [the Windows 10 Specifications page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications), and it is running a legitimate copy of Windows 7 that came pre-installed on the laptop when I purchased it new from the store. After I run the installer, it takes ~1 minute for the following window to pop up (not sure if the taking a whole minute for the window to pop up is a symptom for a problem or not)

[image]

Once I get to that screen and I click next, the Windows 10 Upgrader just closes and nothing happens, even if the laptop is left on overnight. I get a hidden folder named "$Windows.~WS" added to C: (before I click next), but it never grows past its initial size of 47 MB. I've tried this numerous times, each time having to delete the existing $Windows.WS folder to avoid a "Something Happened" error from the upgrader, but the result is always the same: the upgrader closes and the $Windows.WS folder never grows in size.

I downloaded the upgrader from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) because the "Upgrade to Windows 10" icon never popped up in the system tray even though the laptop meets all requirements I can find on "Windows 10 upgrade missing from taskbar" articles / forum posts. The laptop is running a genuine copy of Windows 7 SP1, is compatible according to the Windows 10 Specifications page, has IE 11 installed, [has all updates installed through the Windows 7 automatic updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naDTU.png), and has automatic updates scheduled to install automatically. I didn't want to go through the trouble of figuring out how to enable the system tray icon, so I just installed it manually from the previously mentioned page. I've heard that others have installed it successfully through that page, so I doubt it's a problem with that upgrader.

I reside in the United States, so my regional location shouldn't be an issue.

Quick overview of laptop:

- Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
- AMD A6-3400 1.4 GHz quad core
- 4 GB RAM
- 197 GB free on HDD

[DxDiag results](http://pastebin.com/dmFayuC1)

Is there something wrong with my laptop that is causing the upgrader to close after I click "Next"?

Comment: You are attempting to download Windows 10 Home x64 in the same exact language that Windows 7 Home Premium is in I presume?

Comment: I assume so. My OS is in English, and the picture in the OP has text in English, so I take it the installer is in English as well. I downloaded it through this http://i.imgur.com/o2xelb5.png on this page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10